# I am using .NET Core with C# on Linux, and library *System.Drawing* is missing

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.drawing, .net-standard

#### Error message

> Program.cs(1,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Drawing'
> does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?

Is it possible to fix that? Or I am not meant to be using this library, if I am developing on Linux with C#?

Answer (score 17):

2021:

Quote from *[System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows, Recommended action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action)*:

> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the following libraries:
>
> - ImageSharp
> - SkiaSharp
> - Microsoft.Maui.Graphics

You are able to use System.Drawing for the short term but be aware there is no support.

> Alternatively, you can enable support for non-Windows platforms by setting the System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport runtime configuration switch to true in the runtimeconfig.json file:

> This configuration switch was added to give cross-platform apps that depend heavily on this package time to migrate to more modern libraries. However, non-Windows bugs will not be fixed. In addition, we may completely remove support for non-Windows platforms in a future release, even if you enable it using the runtime configuration switch.

To be able to use System.Drawing on Linux machines, you might also need to install `libgdiplus` as mentioned by @saman-azadi and @alex-from-jitbit.

---

2017:

The `System.Drawing` namespace is at the moment not part of corefx as it relies on the GDI+ features from Windows.

But there [are plans](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325) to support it in the future.

---

But there are multiple alternatives:

[**CoreCompat.System.Drawing**](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)

> CoreCompat.System.Drawing is a .NET Core port of the Mono implementation of System.Drawing. Like System.Drawing in .NET Framework and in Mono, CoreCompat.System.Drawing also relies on GDI+ on Windows. Caution is therefore advised, for the same reasons.

[**ImageSharp**](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp)

> ImageSharp is a brand new, pure managed code, and cross-platform image processing library. Its performance is not as good as that of libraries relying on native OS-specific dependencies, but it remains very reasonable. Its only dependency is .NET itself, which makes it extremely portable: there is no additional package to install, just reference ImageSharp itself, and you’re done.

[**Magick.NET**](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)

> Magick.NET is the .NET wrapper for the popular ImageMagick library. ImageMagick is an open-source, cross-platform library that focuses on image quality, and on offering a very wide choice of supported image formats. It also has the same support for EXIF as ImageSharp.

(The .NET Core build of Magick.NET currently only supports Windows.)

[**SkiaSharp**](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)

> SkiaSharp is the .NET wrapper for Google’s Skia cross-platform 2D graphics library, that is maintained by the Xamarin team. SkiaSharp is now compatible with .NET Core, and is extremely fast.

[**FreeImage-dotnet-core**](https://github.com/matgr1/FreeImage-dotnet-core)

> This library is to the native FreeImage library what Magick.NET is to ImageMagick: a .NET Core wrapper. It offers a nice choice of image formats, good performance, and good visual quality.

---

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) are some good examples and performance analyses of the libraries mentioned above.

Comment: If you're interested in CoreCompat.System.Drawing, you might want to check out `CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2`.

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command on the command line

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

or

```
sudo yum install -y libgdiplus-2.10-9.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has released [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) since which works on Linux too.

UPDATE: They decided to make it "Windows only" in .NET 6. The package will show compile warnings, since it relies on `libgdiplus` which might not be present on some Linux distribution. See *[System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)*.

After trying multiple alternatives we have switched to [PhotoSauce](https://photosauce.net/) (I'm not affiliated, just a recommendation) after trying multiple libraries like ImageSharp (slow, memleaks) SkiaSharp (not managed code) and ImageMagick (not managed code)

Comment: Hello did you by any chance did watermarking? putting a image logo as a watermark on top of the image with ImageSharp?

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to use *System.Drawing* on Linux:

*libgdiplus* causes a serious memory leak on Linux (I tried it on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)) and should not be used ([found here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53663)).

ImageSharp works hard with native code (passing memory pointers) and [OpenCvSharp4](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) became my final choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu Linux and I had the same exact issue. I got it working though. I found out that -pkg:dotnet is required when compiling with the mono compiler even though it isn't when using the Microsoft compiler.

```
C_Sharp_mono:
    mcs main.cs -pkg:dotnet && mono main.exe
C_Sharp_csc:
    csc main.cs && mono main.exe
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) library – a drop-in replacement for System.Drawing that is fully managed and cross-platform. (I'm one of the developers.)

Comment: yeah, but at $4k price. Nope thanks.