# MigraDoc and .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.drawing, migradoc

I have made a class library for PDF-generation. It is implemented using PDFshart-MigraDoc (the core package*). The class library itself is made with .NET Standard as its target framework.

I can use the class library in classic C# projects (like WinForms), but if I try to use it with .NET Core 2.0, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx'. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I guess the reason for this, could be that MigraDoc is using 'System.Drawing' in its implementation, which is (as far as I know) not supported by the .NET Core framework.

However, that doesn't really solve my problem, which is that I need the class library to work for all .NET frameworks. I have tried to include the NuGet package **CoreCompat.System.Drawing**, based on advise from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428405/im-using-net-core-with-c-sharp-on-linux-lib-system-drawing-is-missing). But this has been without effect, probably because MigraDoc is still trying to use the "original" `System.Drawing` library.

Is there any way, in which I can get my class library to work for .NET Core? Or am I out of luck...?

*Note: The MigraDoc Core Package has nothing to do with the .NET Core Framework. The clash of names is merely a coincidence.*

Comment: Do you target Windows only or other platforms also?

Comment: Currently the only target is Windows, yes. It was originally made for a WinForms project, but not a colleague of mine, also wants to use it in a .NET Core 2.0 project.

Answer (score 8):

I found a port for [PDFSharp & MigraDoc here on github](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCorePdf) which uses`System.Drawing.Common` and works with .Net Core.

I had the same and got it fully working.

**Note:** You may need to add `System.Drawing.Common` [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) in your .Net Core project.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Beginning with PDFsharp 6.0.0, PDFsharp supports .NET 6.0 and the Core build no longer relies on System.Drawing.
Beginning with PDFsharp 6.1.0, PDFsharp Core also supports .Netstandard 2.0.

Original answer:
The MigraDoc/PDFsharp Core packages were created long before .NET Core was even announced. "Core" has a different meaning for those MigraDoc packages and they do use System.Drawing.

It's not a bug that the Core package uses System.Drawing.

There are third-party ports of PDFsharp for .NET Core like this one:
https://github.com/groege/PdfSharpCore
Maybe one of these ports is an option for you.

Maybe there are portable replacements for System.Drawing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have noted, that I am aware, that the MigraDoc Core is completely unrelated to .NET Core. I was looking for an alternative, which does not require a complete rewrite of my class library. I will try out some of the MigraDoc ports you mentioned. Replacing System.Drawing doesn't seem like its possible.