# dependence on the operating system?

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

```
private static byte[] BitmapToBytesCode(Bitmap image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            { 
                image.Save(stream,ImageFormat.Png);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

This code only works on Windows. Is it possible to make it system independent?

I have a project that runs on a Linux server and I need to implement one function on this project.

Comment: `System.Drawing` (which is where the `Bitmap` class comes from) does not support Linux by default. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428480/10601203).

Answer (score 0):

Since `System.Drawing.Common` [now only support for windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only), Try to use `ImageSharp` or `OpenCvSharp4`

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

Comment: Are both of these libraries free to use? I have a website which is earning through adsense. I want to develop a tool to compress jpg and png. Can I use these without license? Which one is better?